# Can I hide form after submit?

Tags: php, forms, syntax

I am trying to make a form that will hide on submit and replace it with a thank you msg. Ive tried several things but nothing has worked so far. The code I have now works fine. I would ultimately like the error msg to show on the same page as well with a back button. I am working on that for now. Wish me luck! Thanks for all the help in advance you guys are always awesome!

this is my php

```
<? php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "stormygurl73@yahoo.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
        $error_message. = 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)) {
        $error_message. = 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $last_name)) {
        $error_message. = 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message. = 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }
    $email_message. = "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    echo "We have received your enquiry. We will contact you soon.";
} ?>
```

I am using just a basic contact form. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is good to use Session here.

Comment: Do you call an Ajax form or you use a page submit?

Comment: jawascwipt my friend.

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['email']) { //your code for sending email here and echo thank you } else {?>Your html for form here.<?php } ?>

Comment: Ok now its not submitting.. Im a newbie.

Comment: The form submit action must be your current page (eg. `<form action="contacts.php" method="POST">`) In your script you could write the @pregmatch solution `<?php if(isset($_POST['email']) { //your code for sending email here and echo thank you } else {?>Form html here.<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 3):

It is good to use session in this case.
You can set a session after form submit.
for example

```
$_SESSION['IS_FORM_SUBMIT']=true;
```

and in your view you can check:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['IS_FORM_SUBMIT']) && $_SESSION['IS_FORM_SUBMIT']===true){
    // SHOW FORM
}else{
    //SHOW MESSAGE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to set a redirect with a `$_GET` parameter. If I may give a little hint: when you are validating an email address only check on a '@' and valid characters. You are also checking for the extension but maybe there will be extension with 5 characters or more in  the future.

Comment: He could use the HTML5 mail field type validation as a first filter `<input type="mail" name="email" id="email" />`. Server-side, there are many regular expression for mail address validating, but I suggest to check simplier the mail with an easy regular expression like *^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,5}$*

Comment: I agree with you that you must use `type="email"`(note the 'e'), but what if someones domain extension is: '.com.tr'? Your regular expression will fail and they can't register/fill in the form correctly? I'm sure they will leave the page and never come back.

Comment: You are right. It's just an example. There are many correct regular expressions. There are regular expressions that match for ip addresses, localhost, etc. But usually these are not useful for a production environment. Thanks for the correction.